# How to limit the values in a file using xsl?

Tags: xslt, mule

I had a file in which there are many values.I want the values of a particular field to be limited to 4 character.

example: file1.txt:
aaaa ajhjoaaaaa aaaljlaaaa suygfhjhbj jkjaaaaaaa aajeifgreaaaa

i wnt the content of the file1 to be replaced as(change the 5th word with 4 characters):

aaaa ajhjoaaaaa aaaljlaaaa suygfhjhbj  jkja aajeifgreaaaa

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case and how you intend to use the tagged technologies? What did you try so far?

Comment: Is your input really a text file and not an XML instance? Are you planning on using XSLT 2.0?

Comment: input is a text file: file1.txt .My requirement is to limit the character length of 5th word .

Answer (score 0):

In xslt can't you the xpath substring function:

Example: <xsl:value-of select="substring('Beatles',1,4)" />

Result: 'Beat'

Replace 'Beatles' with the path to you element.